Phaser-capacitor iOS app stuck at blank screen after upgrading capacitor from 5 to 6
I was updating my old phaser-capacitor project form capacitor 5 to 6. Due to lots of ANR issue in capacitor/browser plugin used in the game, I thought it would be worthy upgrade that might improve the ANR situation.
The android looks fine after migrating and works as before
I faced problem of stuck at blank screen shows up on iOS and it does not move to the actual game play screen.
I am not getting any errors on the x code console either.
the last logs in the x-code is as below,
⚡️  Loading app at capacitor://localhost...
⚡️  WebView loaded

Steps I followed to migrate are,
1  cd /project path
2  npm i -D @capacitor/cli@latest
3  npm audit fix
4  npx cap migrate
5  npm install --force 
6  npx cap sync 
7  pod repo update

I tried deleting node_modules , ios folders, clean build and then re-run the migration and sync steps.
When I open the safari dev tools for the installed app the below shows up

So I updated all of the plugins manually to latest and tried building, then also it did not work on iOS.
Looked into this capacitor document and made sure all the softwares are update as below
Software updates

Capacitor 6 needs Xcode version 15.0+
Node.js version 18 or later
latest version of the Capacitor CLI
Capacitor 6 requires Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 or newer
latest compatible version of CocoaPods

my package.json is as below after migration :
 "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor-community/admob": "^5.3.1",
    "@capacitor-community/apple-sign-in": "^5.0.0",
    "@capacitor-community/facebook-login": "^5.0.3",
    "@capacitor-community/keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/device": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/filesystem": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/preferences": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^6.0.0",
    "appsflyer-capacitor-plugin": "^6.12.1",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  }

capacitor.config.json is :
{
  "appId": "com.test.myProject",
  "appName": "myProject",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "webDir": "dist",
}

What I am doing wrong here.
I have checked similar issues on other websites and tried their solutions none worked.
Expected behaviour,
I would like to be able to launch the app on iOS as I used to with Capacitor 5.

This doesn't look like a phaser-framework issue, I would suggest removing this tag (in general use only tags, which might be relevant for the issue).  A tag like node.js and/or npm might be more relevant.
